# CSS width isn't correct/doesn't make sense to me

Tags: html, css, height, width

I got a content section which got a width of 60%. Above that I got an text input with a width of 40%. Next to that input field, there's a submit button.
So according to my math knowledge, the both input fields and the content section should have the same width.
|_________40%_________||____20%____|
|_______________60%________________|
But that isn't the case.
HTML:

```
<input id="plannername" placeholder="Name eingeben" type="text"></input><!--

--><input id="plannersubmit" type="submit" value="eintragen"></input>

<div id="content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#plannername{ /* The text input */
  width:40%;
  background-color:#9eefbc;
  margin-left:20%;
  border:0;
  font-size:2em;
  padding:20px;
}
#plannersubmit{ /* The submit button */
  width:20%;
  background-color:#6dce91;
  border:0;
  font-size:2em;
  padding:20px;
  transition:.2s ease-in-out;
}
#content{
  width:60%;
  background-color:#9eefbc;
  height:500px;
  margin-left:20%;
  padding-top:70px;
  margin-top:3px;
}
```

My full code is here: http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/xgBeaJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `padding` set on the input boxes, to make it part of the total width, you can set `box-sizing: border-box;` or just do it universally:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

A common practice including pseudo elements is:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Note, there is also some default padding and border set from the browser for most of the input elements even if you didn't set any manually. The above solution will still apply.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `box-sizing: border-box` to accomadate the padding. Try adding the following:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Or you can add it to the individual `div`'s as needed.